# my code is not working properly am i doing wrong?

Tags: c

> Maximum Element

You have an empty sequence, and you will be given N queries. Each query is one of these three types:

1 x  -Push the element x into the stack.
2    -Delete the element present at the top of the stack.
3    -Print the maximum element in the stack.
**Input Format**

The first line of input contains an integer, N. The next N lines each contain an above mentioned query. (It is guaranteed that each query is valid.)

**Constraints** 
1≤N≤105 
1≤x≤109 
1≤type≤3
**Output Format**

For each type 3 query, print the maximum element in the stack on a new line.

**Sample Input**

10
1 97
2
1 20
2
1 26
1 20
2
3
1 91
3
**Sample Output**

26
91

> My Code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100000
long a[MAX_SIZE];

int top = -1;

int Push(long x){
    if(top == MAX_SIZE-1){
    }
    top++;
    a[top] = x;
    return 0;
}

int Pop(){
    if(top == -1){
    }
    top--;
    return 0;
}

int Print(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<top+1;i++){
        printf("%ld\n",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    long i, x;
    int n, t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(i=0;i<t;i++){
        scanf("%d",&n);
        switch(n){
            case 1 :
                scanf("%ld",&x);
                Push(x);
                break;
            case 2 :
                Pop();
                break;
            case 3 :
                Print();
                break;  
        }
    }
}
```

> My Output are:
>   Nice try, but you did not pass this test case.
>   Input (stdin)
>   10
>   1 97
>   2
>   1 20
>   2
>   1 26
>   1 20
>   2
>   3
>   1 91
>   3
>   Your Output (stdout)
>   26
>   26
>   91
>   Expected Output
>   26
>   91
>   Compiler Message
>   Wrong Answer

Comment: This is working well in Dev-c compiler but not in hackerrack online compiler

Comment: A more description question title would be helpful...

Comment: Your `Push` and `Pop` functions have `if` statements that do nothing. (It looks like you intended to do some error handing there.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the main problem with the posted code is that the `Print()` function is printing everything rather than following the constraint that it should only print the max value that is currently on the stack.

given the posted code, and cleaning it up a bit and fixing the `Print()` function and using meaningful variable names and using vertical and horizontal spacing for readability results in:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STACK_SIZE (105)

// prototypes
void Print( void );
void Pop( void );
void Push( int value );

int stack[ MAX_STACK_SIZE ];
int stackIndex = -1;

enum action {pushValue=1, popValue=2, printMax=3};

int main( void )
{
    int  value;
    int   numEntries;
    enum   action myAction;

    // get number of entries range 1...105
    scanf("%d",&numEntries);

    for( int i=0; i<numEntries; i++ )
    {
        // get action range 1...3
        scanf("%d", (int*)&myAction);

        switch( myAction )
        {
            case pushValue :
                // get value range 1...109
                scanf("%d",&value);
                Push( value );
                break;

            case popValue :
                Pop();
                break;

            case printMax :
                Print();
                break;
        } // end switch
    } // end for

    return 0;
} // end function: main

void Push(int value)
{
    stackIndex++;
    stack[stackIndex] = value;
}

void Pop()
{
    if( 0 <= stackIndex)
    { // then stack not empty
        stackIndex--;
    }
}

void Print()
{
    int maxValue = -1;
    int i;

    for( i = 0; i<= stackIndex; i++ )
    {
        if( stack[i] > maxValue )
        {
            maxValue = stack[i];
        }
    }

    if( -1 != maxValue )
    {
        printf("%d\n", maxValue);
    }
}
```

has an output, given the posted inputs.

```
26
91
```

Answer (score 0):

The request is:
"For each type 3 query, print the maximum element in the stack on a new line."
and what your code does is printing all of the stack elements.
Btw. what are empty `if` statement bodies in `Push` and `Pop` for?

Comment: Was this intended to answer the question? If not, it should be a comment.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Well, the question was "what am I doing wrong", and that's the answer - printing whole stack instead of the top element.